# How do i update the frame?

Tags: java, swing

Hello i have a Jpanel in which appears an image that says "not image found" when there is no image.

I also created other images with that message in other languages , the problem is that when i make click in the button to change the language al the labels change , but the image no .

How i can make that ?

I have tried it with repaint , revalidate and all that but nothing of that works.

PD: if i come back to the previous window and i change there the language , when i go to the panel in which i have the problem the image is the correct one , so the problem is not that the picture doesn't change.

Solution: I have found the error , the problem was that the piece of the code that changes the image was inside an exception , inside another event , and as the method doesn't execute again that main method it wasn't working properly , thanks to all.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing a **[runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I can assure you that revalidating works, so there must be some flaw in the way you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I have found the error , the problem was that the piece of the code that changes the image was inside an exception , inside another event , and as the method doesn't execute again that main method it wasn't working properly , thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

If `jframe.repaint();` does not work alone use:

```
jframe.invalidate();
jframe.validate();
jframe.repaint();
```

If that does not work, you can force it with:

SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jframe);

**UPDATE**
As @MadProgrammer noted: if this is working is masking a bigger probl in your layout

Comment: updateComponentTreeUI is a bad suggestion at the best of times

Comment: If revalidate/repaint isn't working, then you have an issue with your layout, using updateComponentTreeUI is masking a bigger problem, it's also woefully inefficient

Comment: Nice to know! Updatted answer and my bad practice ;)

Comment: Just had deeper dig and `updateComponentTreeUI` actually relates to updating the look and feel delegate, which isn't really useful when you want to update the layout of container...

Comment: Instead of `invalidate()` and `validate()`, use `revalidate()`.

Comment: Hello guys i tried with all you said to me , but doesn't works with any. I try to revalidate , repaint ,updating the tree but nothing of that works, i will change the main post and add some pictures and code , so you can see easy the problem

Answer (score 0):

Frame is already a visible container and your jpanel is part of your frame, so if you want to update the panel and code is in frame then use the following code in same order-

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

if the repaint code is in panel just called like `validate()` and then `repaint()`. It should work for you.

cheers